What does the factor in HSV node do?
What does the factor in HSV node do mathematically? Does it just multiply final value of node's calculations with values connected to factor pin? Or it uses something like linear interpolation?

Factor is "The amount of influence the node exerts on the image.". So it's supposed to be the same as mixing the original image with the corrected one with a Color Mix node in Mix mode. It's not just multiplication for sure. For anything more specific, I think you would have to look at the source code.

@MartynasŽiemys thank you. Unfortunately, I can't work with the source code. Hope, somebody will provide more details.

It seems blending is done by multiplying background image by inverted factor/alpha and then adding the foreground image multiplied by factor/alpha.
Testing seems identical:


So my guess would be that this is what happens with all color adjustment nodes that have factor - the result is blended with the original. And it seems to look identical even with out of range factor values:


Yes, suppose it's right. Thank you very much!

Seems like it. I am pretty sure that's the math. Like 99.9% :D I am not a developer though like I said, so... I haven't looked at the actual code.

"So my guess would be that this is what happens with all color nodes that have factor - the result is blended with the original. " - it was my guess too in the past, but I think at least one blending mode doesn't work like that.

I somehow intuitively did not mean to include Mix node into "color nodes that have factor", but I guess I did by mistake. I think blending modes are pure math algorithms so yea, it would make sense some might not behave the same as mixing. Thanks for pointing this out. Not really sure how to edit. I was not thinking about Mix node itself at all to be honest.

@MarkusvonBroady Well, the question wasn't about Mix, but the HSV node Factor. There it works like that. But you are correct there are even more than one mode in the Mix Color not working like that. I have a table where I have all the different mix mode calculations, but I won't get to my PC this weekend where I have them, so I cannot provide them yet.

@MartynasŽiemys When working with factors which are floats I would rather use the Vector Math node set to Scale then Multiply and to subtract the factor from 1 you can also use a simple Math node. Of course it is easier to add just one Vector Math node and then duplicate it... yeah, I just realized how stupid I am to always use the matching types and nobody really cares if the results are the same
